# Windows batch file error when backing up Sql database

Tags: mysql, batch-file

the error is after the

```
del "C:\backupforalldbs\tpsdatabase\bk_%backuptime%.sql"
```

Here's the source code:

```
CLS 

SET backuptime=%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~7,2%-%DATE:~4,2%-%TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%

echo %backuptime%

echo Running dump ...

set 7zip_path=

"C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe" --host="localhost" --port="3306" --user="jakedean" --password="jakedean" -Q --result-file="C:\backupforalldbs\tpsdatabase\bk_%backuptime%.sql" jakedean

echo Zipping ...

"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip     "C:\backupforalldbs\tpsdatabase\bk_%backuptime%.zip"         "C:\backupforalldbs\tpsdatabase\bk_%backuptime%.sql"

echo Deleting the SQL file ...

del "C:\backupforalldbs\tpsdatabase\bk_%backuptime%.sql"

timeout /t 5

echo Done!

@pause
```

and here's a print screen of the cmd prompt after executing...

[image: Screenshot]

I've tried everything from  changing files names, shortening the directory, changing the non caps but nothing has worked... :/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the %backuptime% variable is generating slashes, you should find a way to remove them, since windows doesn't allow files with a slash in it's name. That's what's bugging your command.

[image]

List of unsupported characters:

[image]

Check the file name in the directory before you attempt to delete it.

Comment: the -20-59.sql is a file inside the bk_-01-2 folder, they're not the same file

Comment: Then instead of using a slash `/` in your command, use backslash \

Comment: I don't know how or why it's generating that / in the del command, but yes the variable id generating it, hmm

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by replacing the

`SET backuptime=%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~7,2%-%DATE:~4,2%-%TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%`

with

`SET backuptime=%TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%`

The date was adding a / which isn't allowed in file names which caused the error. Also the date wasn't setting the correct data, it kept setting 01-02...

The whole .bat file now looks like this

```
@echo off

CLS 

SET backuptime=%TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%

echo %backuptime%

echo Running dump ...

set 7zip_path=

"C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe" --host="localhost" --port="3306" --user="jakedean" --password="jakedean" -Q --result-file="C:\backupforalldbs\tpsdatabase\bk_%backuptime%.sql" jakedean

echo Zipping ...

"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "C:\backupforalldbs\tpsdatabase\bk_%backuptime%.zip" "C:\backupforalldbs\tpsdatabase\bk_%backuptime%.sql"

echo Deleting the SQL file ...

del "C:\backupforalldbs\tpsdatabase\bk_%backuptime%.sql"

timeout /t 5

echo Done!
```

Comment: Format of date and time string of the environment variables __DATE__ and __TIME__ depend on Windows region and language settings and are therefore not identical on all computers. So to get a backup date/time string in wanted format you either have to adapt the line with the substitutions to date/time format of your machine or use `wmic` to get current date and time in a region independent format and use the right substitutions. Run in a command prompt window `echo %DATE% %TIME%` to see format on your machine. Next run `set /?` and read help to understand how the string substitutions work.